How to use Moran's I to analyse the structure of savannah tree population?
I would like to analyze the interaction between trees in savannah.
I have a set of data where each tree is located using an x and y value.
I want to consider that every position that is not concerned by x and y value is empty.
Those coordinate are comprise between 0 and 100 for x and y. There are 77 trees studied.
Thanks for your help
sry for bad english
W <- dnearneigh(coordsplacette1, d1=0,d2=20,longlat = TRUE)

W <- nb2listw(W, style = "W")

This is my weighted matrix which is then transformed into a list.
What I don't understand is how to put the presence absence value as the x in moran.test(x, listw = W) because I only study this and not a value associated to each position. I tried applicating a value of 1 to each tree but it does not work.
